# How to assign array multiple values with isset input on form submition in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, isset

I am trying get a form submitted values in array after `isset()` but it store only last `isset()` value in array. What is the right way to get all not null values in array to pass to insert function.

```
$table = 'booking';
if(isset($_POST['tourID'])){
    $data = array('tour_fk' => $this->input->post('tourID'));
}
if(isset($_POST['bookingNumber'])){
    $data = array('booking_number' => $this->input->post('bookingNumber'));
}
$query = $this->dashboard_model->insert($table, $data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way is to add new keys to `$data` instead of reassigning it:

```
if (isset($_POST['tourID'])){
    $data['tour_fk'] = $this->input->post('tourID');
}
if (isset($_POST['bookingNumber'])){
    $data['booking_number'] = $this->input->post('bookingNumber');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve like this.Make a array of all not null keys with values.Not need to write `isset()` for each posted items.Just make use of `foreach` loop.And achieve your result.

```
$table = 'booking';
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    if(isset($_POST[$key])) {
        $data[$key]=$this->input->post($key);
    }
}
//print_r($data);
```

Here is an example for you..

```
$array = array('tour_fk'=>1,'booking_number'=>11,'empty_field'=>NULL);
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
    if(isset($array[$key])) {
        $data[$key]=$value;
    }
}
    print_r($data);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [tour_fk] => 1 [booking_number] => 11 )//without null values
```